# Reading CSV files into python with utf-8-sig BOM and latin-1 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I have a csv file that seems to be encoded in UTF-8 based on the BOM present at the start of the file. However, when I try to open it, I get an error

```
import io
import chardet
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pandas import read_csv

filename = './sample.zip'

objs = []
frames = []

with ZipFile(filename) as zf:
    zipinfo_objs = [ zi for zi in zf.infolist() 
        if zi.filename.endswith(".csv") ]

    for zipinfo_obj in zipinfo_objs:
        obj = zf.read(zipinfo_obj.filename)
        objs.append(obj)

    print("Bytes Objects:", [type(obj) for obj in objs])
    print("Encoding:", chardet.detect(objs[0]))
    print("BOM:", objs[0][:4])

    buffer = io.BytesIO(objs[0])
    frame = read_csv(buffer)
    frames.append(frame)
```

yields

```
Bytes Objects: [<class 'bytes'>]
Encoding: {'encoding': 'UTF-8-SIG', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
BOM: b'\xef\xbb\xbf"'

...
...

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

However, if I specify the encoding as latin-1 in the attempt to decode the buffer, like:
`frame = read_csv(buffer, encoding="latin-1")`.
I get a success and pandas is able to read in the dataframe.

This file was generated from Adobe Analytics and apparently there was no option specify the format of the export besides giving the user an option to choose a CSV or a Tableau file.

**My questions are:**

- Is it a typical occurrence for CSV files to be encoded in latin-1 and include the UTF-8-SIG BOM at the beginning of the file?
- Should I be checking for encoding differently / extracting data differently?

Comment: To me, it looks like you have a corrupt file. It looks a lot like an error to put a UTF-8 encoded BOM and then continue with Latin-1 – unless somebody *really, really* wanted to start a file with the characters `ï»¿`. Note: you can't be sure the file is actually Latin-1 just because it was processed without an exception – Latin-1 accepts any byte sequence, even a binary file like a JPG image.

Comment: I'll agree to that. I've had files that the encoding was unknown but UTF-8 worked on some lines then an error happened. I tried to use latin-1 and indeed was able to finish looping through my file. The file was 10GB with 300 million lines or so, I didn't find out part was corrupted until later on. The latin-1 encoding did not help me there.

Comment: Are there any valid UTF-8 sequences in the file besides the starting BOM?  As others have said `latin1` decodes anything with no error, so that is no guarantee of the encoding.  More likely the file has corruption.  You could `open(...,encoding='utf-8-sig',errors='replace')` and see what the result looks like.